# Can't fetch all data from Firestore React-Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I can't fetch all data from Firestore in my react native app. I can fetch data when I add a limit(200) parameter but when I take away the limit parameter my app crashes. I need to display all the data and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, here is my code:

```
  const listingsRef = firebase.firestore().collection(ServerConfiguration.database.collection.LISTINGS);

  if (categoryId === '') {
    console.log('Kommer vi hit???');

    return listingsRef
      .where('isApproved', '==', isApproved)
      .limit(2000)
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const data = [];

        if (querySnapshot !== undefined) {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const listing = doc.data();
            if (favorites && favorites[doc.id] === true) {
              listing.saved = true;
            }
            data.push({ ...listing, id: doc.id });
          });

          console.log('KOMMERR datan? : ', data);

          callback(data);
        }
      });
  }
```

I have tried to use get instead of on Snapshot, and I get the same results. I have been stuck for days!

Comment: And how many documents are in that collection?

Comment: It's an anitpattern to try to fetch every document in a collection. You will always want to implement some kind of pagination.

Comment: There is 1000+ data that is being fetched from firebase

Comment: i don't know what paginate is, do you have a link with any good documentation for this?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#node.js

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the limit with getting and getting all the records that satisfy your condition.

```
const listingsRef = firebase.firestore().collection(ServerConfiguration.database.collection.LISTINGS);

  if (categoryId === '') {
    console.log('Kommer vi hit???');

    return listingsRef
      .where('isApproved', '==', isApproved)
      .get()
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const data = [];

        if (querySnapshot !== undefined) {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const listing = doc.data();
            if (favorites && favorites[doc.id] === true) {
              listing.saved = true;
            }
            data.push({ ...listing, id: doc.id });
          });

          console.log('KOMMERR datan? : ', data);

          callback(data);
        }
      });
  }
```

But its always a good idea to paginate your results when you have large amount of data